# Advantage of Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jersey

Spring is a popular framework, however I have difficulties to see in which situation the framework would actually help.

Currently I'm using the following:
* Tomcat
* Jersey
* Jackson
* Hibernate

Together this results in a Webservice, created by annotations, automatic JSON (un)marshalling and a comfortable Object/Relational Mapping.

So honestly at the moment I'm not missing anything, but I might just not know what great thing I'm missing... Could you help me out with this?
Thank you

Comment: Its big advantage is in helping creating testable code. Dependencies injected in the production runtime are replaced with mocked implementations/proxies in testing scope making the testing in isolation PoC.

Comment: Boris, you don't need spring to do Dependency Injection. The only benefit that spring provides is that if you use the xml configuration, the wiring of the beans is done through configuration rather than in static code. If you use annotations (aka static code) and autowiring is almost the same as having some classes which are solely responsible for the wiring of the beans. Having said that, I quite like Spring, but it's not a good solution for most problems.

Comment: Thanks fr the answer already. I'm asking this, since I'm think about migrating to spring, which however would take quite some time, and I'm simply not sure if it is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, Spring offers you uniform way to control dependencies between your objects. This is called `inversion of control` or `dependency injection`. Using it you can create pluggable, testable code that is easy to maintain.

In addition it gives you gazillion utility classes that just make life easier. For example, Hibernate is much easier to maintain via Spring facilities. It kind of brings together many different technologies under the same roof.

Answer (score 2):

Spring is a big framework providing a lot of functionality. It's hard to talk about advantages without knowing what functionality are you trying to use in the project.

Most probably you talk about Spring as an IoC container. It is very important part of Spring, but there is also AOP, transaction management, JDBC abstraction layer, authentication and authorization, testing and some more.